# load website from the server

Tags: javascript, html, web, server

I am looking to create a website that takes a website URL as input and loads it from the server that the html page is on not the computer that the user is on like iframe does by default. So far all the techniques I have tried load the website from the users computer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Very vague question ...  would I be right in saying that what you want is a visitor to your website enter, for example, `http://somedoman.com/page.html` and your website loads it?

Comment: Sorry, writing questions is not my strong suit. I want the server to load the page. But i want the server to load it on the server instead of the user's computer loading the requested page

Comment: Right, so you'll need to tell us a little about the server.

Comment: "i want the server to load it on the server" -> ???

Comment: Well its registered through domain.com and the platform is debian. What all do you need to know

Comment: I mean load the page through the servers internet connection instead of the users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about what it seems you would first.

Have a server ready to go, create a file called "**something.html/php**" then you would navigate to the page by putting the url in your search bar and profit? This question is beyond confusing though.

Comment: Kind of but i want the site to load an external page through ITS internet connection, not the users

Comment: You can't load a web page through the servers internet that's not possible, the user has to connect to the page by them selves in order for them to see the content. Anyway, I hope my answer helped.

Comment: @EthanMylastnameisformetoknowa Thanks, I am glad I could help! If this answer helped you please consider clicking the check mark on the side of the question to mark this as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to build a browser inside a browser? weired.

Anyway, this may help.

```
function getUrl() {
    var url = prompt("Enter URL", "");
    location.href = url;
}
```

Then call `getUrl` when your `body` loads.

```
<body onload="getURL()"></body>
```

Comment: I understand it may sound odd, but its seems like the only solution

Comment: Ok, did the answer help?